# How to delete database from SQL Server if .mdf and .ldf file is removed from the machine?

Tags: sql-server

I have restore database into SQL Server as WMDATA.

One day my friend using my machine and removed `.mdf` and `.ldf` file for WMDATA.

Now I want to remove `WMDATA` database from my SQL Server but it gives me error for `.mdf` and `.ldf` file.

Answer (score 4):

`DROP DATABASE WMDATA` should work, because it will [drop a database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx) even if it is [suspect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190442.aspx).

If that doesn't help, you should add some more useful information: what version of MSSQL; how are you dropping the database; what is the error message etc. You might also get a better answer on the [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) sites.

Comment: +1 You may get an error upon executing the drop statement (e.g. 'Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\Foo\Bar.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".' but this does not mean the drop didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I run into this issue as well, while trying to delete some localdb databases through SSMS and `DROP DATABASE` didn't work for me. However, I found that it is possible to "recreate" the database after an unsuccessful deletion. I did the following:

1. Delete the database, get error that .mdf files are missing.
2. Create new database with the same name.
3. Delete the database again, this time without errors.

PS: If you don't do step 1, you get an error in step 2 that a database with that name already exists.

Answer (score -2):

Right click on the DB > Delete

Uncheck "Delete backup and restore history information for databases"
Check "Close existing connections"

And hit OK.

Comment: Right click on the database and choose "Policies"->"Delete Health States".  It should then be removed from the list.  Refresh the instance databases and it should disappear from the list.